# Probability that two random positive integers are coprime

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $P$ be the probability measure on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(\{n\}) = \frac{1}{2^n}$. What is then the probability that two random integers $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ are coprime? In other words, what is 
$$
    \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lfloor \frac{1}{(m,n)}\rfloor}{2^{m+n}}
$$